# sortable with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using following code for make my divs sortable

```
$('.outersortable').sortable({ 
    handle: ".drag", 
    cursor: "e-size",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight", 
    axis: "y" });
```

I want to run ajax call and save changes (order of div) and also it just make divs dragable but not replace divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use sortable `update` event whitch is fired when user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.

You grab current elements order with `$('.outersortable').sortable("toArray");` and use jQuery `ajax` function to send it to backend.

**Full example:**

```
$('.surEdOuterSortable').sortable({ 
    handle: ".spritesHandlerIcon", 
    cursor: "e-size",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight", 
    axis: "y" 
    update: function(event, ui) {
        order = $('.outersortable').sortable("toArray");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller/action',
            data: {order:order},                        
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks can i run foreach loop on "order " right after $.ajax ({...});

Comment: Yes, you can use `for` loop on `order` iteams to iterate them. It is javascript array of string id's of `li` elements.